# Proof by divisibility. Should I choose $a=p$ and $b=p^2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

A problem from a university exam paper.

> Evaluate $\gcd(ab,p^4)$ and $\gcd(a+b,p^4)$, given that $\gcd(a,p^2)=p$ and $\gcd(b,p^3)=p^2$

This site has solved this problem once. But I have a specific question in my approach. This problem that I have found in some exam paper doesn't say that $p$ is prime. It looks like prime but is it obvious that $p$ **must be** prime?

Anyway, here is my workout.

$$\gcd(a,p^2)=p, \space\space \gcd(b,p^3)=p^2$$

We have $p$ that $p\mid a,\space p \mid p^2$. Again $p^2\mid b, \space\space p^2\mid p^3$.

Now $$p^2\mid b, \space\space p^2\mid p^3, \space\space p \mid p^2 \\ \therefore p\mid p^3\\p\mid b\\\therefore p\mid a,\space p \mid p^2,\space\space p \mid b,\space\space p \mid p^3\\ \therefore p\mid a+b$$.

Here $$\because p\mid a,\space p \mid p^2,\space\space p \mid b,\space\space p \mid p^3,\space\space p^2\mid p^3,\space\space p^2\mid b\\\space\space \\\text{and} \space\space \gcd(a,p^2)=p,\space\space \gcd(b,p^3)=p^2$$.

Hence is it correct to choose $a=p$ and $b=p^2$? If it is correct then $$\gcd(a+b,p^4)=\gcd(p+p^2,p^4)=p\\ \text{and}\space\space \gcd(ab,p^4)=\gcd(p\cdot p^2,p^4)=\gcd(p^3,p^4)=p^3$$

If choosing $a=p$ and $b=p^2$ is not correct please provide or suggest the correct way. Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the problem statement doesn't say that $p$ is prime (and your book, or whatever it is you have, hasn't said that in general, the letter $p$ will always represent a prime), then it's not obvious that $p$ must be a prime.

Comment: In that case is my workout correct from the beginning to end?

Comment: You can't "pick" $a$ and $b$. The fact that $p$ divides $a+b$ is correct (it follows from the fact that $p$ divides both $a$ and $b$). It should also be straightforward for you to verify that $p^3$ divides $ab$ to et you started on the fist $\gcd$. The trick now is to show that the $\gcd$ of $a+b$ and $p^2$ must be just $p$, and that the $\gcd$ of $ab$ and $p^4$ must be just $p^3$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin, I have got your clue. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When you said *This site has solved this problem once*, did you mean this post: [Evaluate $\gcd(ab,p^4)$ and $\gcd(a+b,p^4)$, given that $\gcd(a,p^2)=p$ and $\gcd(b,p^3)=p^2$, where $p$ is a prime.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/964251)?

Comment: @MartinSleziak, Yes, I went through the nice solutions to the problem given in the link